# How to decode string with unicode

Tags: python, unicode, request

I use requests modular to get response from url of some website by this:

```
response = requests.get(request_url)
result = response.json()
```

Thus I get a result with type of dict with sample value like following:

```
result = {u'bids': [[u'16.85', u'53.4125', u'900'], [u'16.83', u'713.0125', u'12000']], u'asks': [[u'9999999999.00', u'0.0001', u'1000000']]}
```

I just wonder how to get a dict with values of their original formation:

```
result = {bids: [[16.85, 53.4125, 900], [16.83, 713.0125, 12000]], asks: [[123.00', 0.02, 10]]}
```

That is, change the unicodes to their formal formation, let float type be float type, int to int, str to str.

Please provide some solution and thanks.

Comment: They are all strings in the *original JSON source*. How would you determine what is a float and what is an integer here?

Comment: You don't need to convert the unicode keys to strings here; Python will auto-encode / decode as needed and your keys are using only ASCII characters, making that all work. If your list values follow a pattern, then just use `float()` on the first two and `int()` on the 3rd value for each nested list.

Comment: @user3856011: terrible suggestion, please don't use eval() with data pulled from an untrusted source.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: That's right, but if he decides that the source trustworthy, then it's the easiest solution

Comment: @user3856011: no, the better solution is to follow the pattern; that way if the pattern breaks so does your conversion. **At best** use `ast.literal_eval()` to only allow for Python literals.

Comment: @user3856011 I think ast.literal_eval() is a potential solution. Will you or anyone else give a formal answer to my question so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse any string representation of an object to the object (like "[1, 2, 3]" to [1, 2, 3]) you have two options:

There is a built-in function called eval, which does this kind of things, but it is insecure, because it parses any kind of python expression that returns a value and  someone who knows python and its syntax could damage your system a lot, if you parse his expression.

Another option is the literal_eval function from the ast module. It parses the given expression like eval, but "The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None." (from https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). This more secure and is the recommended way to parse data pulled from an untrusted source.